# USB errors and warnings on dmesg

Tags: 12.04, usb, 14.04

I was using **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** and booting was very slow and the following error appeared many times on the screen while loading, like this:

```
unable to enumerate USB device on port 7
unable to enumerate USB device on port 7
unable to enumerate USB device on port 7
unable to enumerate USB device on port 7
...
```

Running command `dmesg` showed this error hundreds of times and there was another repetitive message:

```
new full speed USB device number xx using ehci_hcd
```

(Replacing "xx" with two different numbers every time).

To avoid this, I upgraded to **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** and the message `unable to enumerate USB device on port 7` has disappeared, but the other message keeps going on and `dmesg` is full of this message `new full speed USB device number xx using ehci_hcd`.

I'm using an HP Pavilion dv6 on a x64 machine with Kernel: 3.13.0-24-generic

This happens even with no devices plugged into the laptop and all the USB connectors work.

Do you have any ideas on this? Is this a real problem? Is this a software or a hardware issue? When googling, I've seen that this seemed to be a problem in year 2008. So, I don't know what's happening here!

Note: Another laptop (Toshiba Portege) doesn't show any of these messages on `dmesg` and it's running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

the message

```
new full speed USB device number xx using ehci_hcd
```

Only is information... but the message

```
unable to enumerate USB device on port 7
```

is one error with the SO and the device, olds devices in old ports cause many errors. But example, i have two computers... my beauty old G41 Chipset based with ubuntu 13.1 and my Work PC with i5  under ubuntu 12.04 LTS... on my old pc with olds ports fail mounted my tablet like USB Device... :(

Comment: I don't think that the message `new full speed USB device number xx using ehci_hcd` is simply information when it appears hundreds of times... I think something is not going fine inside :S The curious think is that all USB ports work as expected.